# Can I use the `this` keyword to update an object from its own member function?

Tags: c++

I'm wondering if I can replace an entire data structure by creating a new structure inside a member function and assigning it to the `this` keyword.  Say I have a data structure called `object` and it has a member function called update, as follows:

```
struct object {
  //guts of the object
}


object newobj(int i) {
  //function to create a new object from an integer
}

object::update(parms) {
  //member function of objects
  this = newobj(1)
}
```

Can I update `object` this way? If not, how can I update all the values in the object without updating each of its elements separately, from within a member function?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Note that `this` itself is a value and duplicated in many places. So by changing a single `this` value you haven't actually modified the content of the object that all the other `this` point to.

Comment: I'd like to update the `object` structure from within its member function, calling another function that returns the type `object`. The other solution would be create a new `object` in the member function, then assign the values of each of its members to members of `this`.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve, but it sounds like changing the content of an object warrants creating a new object of a different class. At least in a language like C++ you can't change members on the fly; you will want more dynamically typed languages like Python or Javascript for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This will change just the `this` pointer. What you can do however is something along the lines of:

```
*this = newobj(1);
```

which will do a value copy (or invoke move semantics).

Comment: You can't change `this`.  It's not assignable.

Comment: ... will **attempt** to change the `this` pointer.  Which is a compile error.

Comment: Reread my answer, I'm not re-assigning to `this`, i'm assigning to `*this`, which does work.

Comment: This would require overloading the [copy constructor](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/) but will leave the structure of the destination object intact. If I understand the question correctly then Noam wants to change the *structure* (i.e. members) of an existing object.

Comment: No, I'm not trying to change the structure. The members of the existing object could remain the same, but their values would change.

Comment: @NoamRoss: Perhaps clarify your question that you're trying to change the *values* of the structure's elements, not the structure itself.